# SubStrings from String Array iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an array, see below,

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"45 x 2",@"76 x 3",@"98 x 3", nil];
```

Now  i want all the string which is right to the character "x" in to another array. That is i need an array with elements `@"2",@"3",@"3"` from the above array.

How can i achieve this??
thanks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"45 x 2",@"76 x 3",@"98 x 3", nil];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *string in myArray)
{
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"x"];
    if(array.count > 1)
        [tempArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"45 x 2",@"76 x 3",@"98 x 3", nil];
    NSMutableArray *suffixArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *el in myArray)
    {
        NSRange range = [el rangeOfString:@"x"];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) [prefixArray addObject:@""];
        NSString *suffix = [el substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length];
        [suffixArray addObject:suffix];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate in for loop and achieve this

```
NSArray *splitedString = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexVal] componentsSeparatedByString: @"x"];


    if ([splitedString count]>1)
{
            NSString *prefixString=[splitedString objectAtIndex:1];
            //Add this to ur new array
}
```